# GUI parts not showing up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Some parts of the GUI don't show up.

```
public  class HospitalRecord extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener, ItemListener{

    BorderLayout bl;
    FlowLayout fl;
    GridLayout gl;

    JPanel jpSouth;
    JPanel jpCenter;
    JPanel jpNorth; 

    JLabel lblName;
    JLabel lblSurname;
    JLabel lblPhone;
    JLabel lblHeight;
    JLabel lblBirthYear;
    JLabel lblDepartment;

    JTextField txtName;
    JTextField txtSurname;
    JTextField txtPhone;
    JTextField txtHeight;


    JRadioButton rbEmergency;
    JRadioButton rbControl;
    JRadioButton rbOperation;

    JCheckBox cbocigaretteusage;
    JCheckBox cboalcoholusage;
    JCheckBox cbodrugusage;

    JComboBox jcAgeEntries;

    JButton jbSubmit;
    JButton jbPrint;

    JList jLdepartment;


    public HospitalRecord() {
        super("Registration Form");

        bl=new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(bl);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        jpSouth = new JPanel();
        add(jpSouth,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        south();


        jpCenter = new JPanel();
        add(jpCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        center();


        jpNorth = new JPanel();
        add(jpNorth,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        north();


        txtName.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void north(){

         lblBirthYear = new JLabel("Birth Year");
          Integer[] comboData = new Integer[114];
            for (int i = 0; i < comboData.length; i++) {
                comboData[i] = 1900 + i;
            }
         jcAgeEntries = new JComboBox(comboData);
         jcAgeEntries.addMouseListener(this);

         String[] listData = new String[3];
            listData[0] = "Accident and emergency";
            listData[1] = "Ear nose and throat (ENT)";
            listData[2] = "General surgery";

            lblDepartment = new JLabel("Department Type");
            jLdepartment= new JList(listData);
            jLdepartment.addMouseListener(this);


         jpNorth.add(lblBirthYear);
         jpNorth.add(jcAgeEntries);
         jpNorth.add(lblDepartment);
         jpNorth.add(jLdepartment);


    }


    public void center(){
        gl = new GridLayout(3,3);
        jpCenter.setLayout(gl);

        lblName = new JLabel("Name");
        lblSurname = new JLabel("Surname");
        lblPhone = new JLabel("Phone");
        lblHeight = new JLabel("Height");

        txtName = new JTextField("Name");
        txtSurname = new JTextField("Surname");
        txtPhone = new JTextField("Phone");
        txtHeight = new JTextField("Height");
        txtName.addMouseListener(this);
        txtSurname.addMouseListener(this);
        txtPhone.addMouseListener(this);
        txtHeight.addMouseListener(this);

         rbEmergency = new JRadioButton("Emergency");
         rbControl = new JRadioButton("Control");
         rbOperation = new JRadioButton("Operation");
         add(rbEmergency);
         add(rbControl);
         add(rbOperation);



         cbocigaretteusage = new JCheckBox("Cigarette Usage");
         cboalcoholusage = new JCheckBox("Alcohol Usage");
         cbodrugusage = new JCheckBox("Drug Usage");
         add(cbocigaretteusage);
         add(cboalcoholusage);
         add(cbodrugusage);



        jpCenter.add(lblName);
        jpCenter.add(txtName);
        jpCenter.add(lblSurname);
        jpCenter.add(txtSurname);
        jpCenter.add(lblPhone);     
        jpCenter.add(txtPhone); 
        jpCenter.add(lblHeight);        
        jpCenter.add(txtHeight);    



    }

    public void south(){
        fl = new FlowLayout();
        jpSouth.setLayout(fl);

        jbSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        jbSubmit.addActionListener(this);
        jpSouth.add(jbSubmit);
    }

    public void printInfo(){
        String info = txtName.getText()+" "+txtSurname.getText()+" "+txtPhone.getText()+" ";
        int yes_no = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, info);
        if(yes_no == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");
        }
        else if(yes_no == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter again");
            txtName.setText("");
            txtSurname.setText("");
            txtPhone.setText("");
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Canceled");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == jbPrint){
            printInfo();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==txtName){
            txtName.setText("");        
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==txtSurname){
            txtSurname.setText("");     
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==txtPhone){
            txtPhone.setText("");       
        }
        else{

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Comment: which parts don't show up?

Comment: North side totally show up center not at all and south show up too

Comment: You're doing add(rbEmergency);
        add(rbControl);
        add(rbOperation); in center function to add these elements directly to the frame.. but where on the frame? the frame is using a borderlayout, you can't just use that add.

Comment: okey i fixed it the missing part was "JpCenter." i added this before "add(rbEmergency)" etc. thanks for help :)

Comment: Check my answer. i tested it... it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In center() you have:

```
    add(rbEmergency);
    add(rbControl);
    add(rbOperation);
```

which is adding these items to the frame directly, you want to add them to the center panel. So increase your center panel size to 16 since u have 6 add(...) in center().

```
gl = new GridLayout(4, 4);
jpCenter.setLayout(gl);
```

Now change these in center() to:

```
    jpCenter.add(rbEmergency);
    jpCenter.add(rbControl);
    jpCenter.add(rbOperation);
    jpCenter.add(cbocigaretteusage);
    jpCenter.add(cboalcoholusage);
    jpCenter.add(cbodrugusage);
```

You can also add a nice display method to your class

```
public void display()
{
    this.pack();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

So to use it, just do

```
new HospitalRecord().display();
```

Comment: Thank you so much again i tried that also works well too